# Does Object.defineProperty check if the property is defined?

Tags: javascript, json, object, properties

I need to define property for a javascript object.
`var obj = {};`
`obj['prop1'] = 1`

In the above way, we can define the property.

Now, let us use `Object.defineProperty`
`var obj = {};`
`Object.defineProperty(obj,'prop1',{value:1});` 
this is alternate way.

what is the difference between the two?
Does `Object.defineProperty` check if the property is already defined or not??

 I believe `obj['prop1'] = 1` checks for the property

thanks :)
**EDIT**

Any performance variation in between those?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither a direct object access, nor `Object.defineProperty` will "*check*" for existing properties. The only difference between those two is the possbility, to modify *property descriptor values*.

Property descriptors are

- enumerable
- configurable
- writable

which are all set to `true` by using *direct property access*. With `Object.defineProperty` you have the option to set these properties individually. I suggest you read this [MDN articl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)e to get an idea about the meanings.

If for instance, a propertie owns the flag `configurable=false`, you cannot overwrite or delete it (which might be the case for your issue).

---

Concerning performance:

Since `Object.defineProperty` is a function which needs to get executed each time, it has to be slower than a direct access on the object. I created this little benchmark:

http://jsperf.com/property-access-with-defineproperty

However, even if the difference looks drastically, you may not forget the value and reason for `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: @DisplayName: I added a new section.

Comment: @jAndy—while MDN is good for examples, the definitive reference for language features is [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.6).

Comment: @RobG: I guess that pretty much depends on the situation. The ECMA reference is written very formal and spec'ish while MDN reads in a more natural way. In this instance, MDN is more than enough to explain the nature of things, but if you're looking for the real specification deal, I'd agree.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

> When the property already exists, Object.defineProperty() attempts to modify the property according to the values in the descriptor and the object's current configuration. If the old descriptor had its configurable attribute set to false (the property is said to be "non-configurable"), then no attribute besides writable can be changed. In that case, it is also not possible to switch back and forth between the data and accessor property types.
>
> If a property is non-configurable, its writable attribute can only be changed to false.
>
> A TypeError is thrown when attempts are made to change non-configurable property attributes (besides the writable attribute) unless the current and new values are the same.

Answer (score 1):

in both cases, if property exists it's value will be overwritten, otherwise it will be created